# Angular input element binding doesn't work for an object. How do I get it to follow the json value?

Tags: angular

Given:

```
this.setting.json =[{
  name: "Configuration name setting",
  elements: [
    { propertyName: 'canSeeOwnJob', checked: "true" },
    { propertyName: 'canSeeAdminJob', checked: "false" },
    { propertyName: 'canSeeGroup2Jobs', checked: "false" },
  ]
}];
```

And this Angular Binding
[image]

And here's the output:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get the checkbox to follow the checked value of the json?

I've tried:

```
checked='element.checked'
[checked] = 'element.checked'
[(checked)] = 'element.checked'

checked={{element.checked}}
[checked]={{element.checked}}
```

And other things like:

```
checked = onGetCheckedValue(element) which returns proper values!
```

**Solution**

Was to change the json "checked" value from string to boolean.

```
 this.setting.json =[{
    name: "Configuration name setting",
    elements: [
    { propertyName: 'canSeeOwnJob', checked: true },
    { propertyName: 'canSeeAdminJob', checked: false },
    { propertyName: 'canSeeGroup2Jobs', checked: false },
    ]
    }];
```

Both these bindings worked:

[image]

Comment: You should use [(ngModel)]='element.checked' instead of [checked]='element.checked'. You probably will need some modules like FormsModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checked property should be of type boolean

Change your data as like below,

```
this.setting.json =[{
  name: "Configuration name setting",
  elements: [
    { propertyName: 'canSeeOwnJob', checked: true },
    { propertyName: 'canSeeAdminJob', checked: false },
    { propertyName: 'canSeeGroup2Jobs', checked: false },
  ]
}];
```

And change your inner html as like below,

```
<div>
  {{element.propertyName}} is {{element.checked}} but shows up as :
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="element.checked" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this :

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="element.checked">
```

And element.checked should be 'boolean' type

added :

If you want to show just checkbox info

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="element.checked">
```

And "element.checked" should be 'boolean' type. if you use string, it always show checked box.

Comment: Thanks Jihoon, it's not working for me.  My app.module has imported both forms and reactiveforms. But I do not have a form element in markup.

Comment: @JohnPeters I added answer. Could you try this one?